# How to properly handle Forms Authentication Ticket when using a Cookie-less Session

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, cookieless

I am pretty sure I do not have a unique problem, but I have searched all over google and this site and I haven't found a solid answer for what I am looking for. So I wanted to explain myself to see if I could get any help on this issue:

We (my co-workers and I) determined that we need have cookie-less Sessions because our users require multiple sessions to get their work done in a more productive fashion.

**Example**
 
Bob the user could have initiated a long running process in window A and in order to continue working Bob will open window B which spawns a new session. This is necessary in order to not disturb what is going on in window A. Every time Bob opens a new window, he has to log in again.

**The Problem**
I am not really sure if this is a real problem or not, hence my reason for asking. The problem I *think* I have discovered is that each time Bob logs in, the current Forms Authentication Ticket (and Cookie) are over-written. Now I do not understand how this is okay or why the previous Session/Window combo is still valid after Bob logs in a second time. Since the ticket was over-written doesn't that mean the first Session/Window combo should end because the ticket is no longer valid? This is with respect to:

```
Request.IsAuthenticated //Making sure the supplied ticket is valid
```

**Questions**
So since the Forms Authentication Ticket (and Cookie) are being over written, what does this mean?

- Should I be concerned that the ticket (and Cookie) are being over written?
- During login, should I be intercepting the ticket (if any) and checking for its expiration? If it is not expired should I try to renew the ticket or just make a new one?

  ```
  FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(ticket) //Just an example
  ```
- If I am using a cookie-less session should I just use cookie-less Forms Authentication too? The point of doing this would be to make each Session/Window 100% independent of each other. No over-writing would occur anymore. Is there a draw back to this? I can't think of any.

PS: I know the cookie is just a container for what ever is being stored in it, like a Key Value pair.

Additonal Info...

**Forms Authentication Ticket:**
IsPersistent set to true
Ticket Version 2

**Forms Cookie:**
Key = FormsCookieName (from web.config  tag)
Value = Hashed Ticket

**Web.Config:**

```
<sessionState 
    cookieless="true" 
    mode="SQLServer" 
    sqlConnectionString="..." 
    timeout="300" 
regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />

<forms name="FormsCookieName" 
    path="../" 
    loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
    protection="All" 
    timeout="300"
    slidingExpiration="true" >
</forms>
```

Comment: Is this solution in a webfarm where there are multiple web servers?

Comment: Thanks for adding that tag. Currently there is no webfarm, but there potentially could be. However I know that wouldn't be implemented for a long time. So no, no web farm. I just want to make sure I am doing this right since I know it can potentially blow up in my face if I don't do it right.